# Установка пакетов с nuget (InstaSharp)

Tags: c#, uwp, instagram, nuget

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой. После установки пакета с "nuget" пакета "InstaSharp", приложение не запускается, с такой ошибкой

"Полезная нагрузка содержит два или более файлов с одним и тем же путем назначения "Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll". Исходные файлы: 
C:\Users\User.nuget\packages\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives\4.0.0\lib\dotnet\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
C:\Users\User.nuget\packages\runtime.win.Microsoft.Win32.Primitives\4.3.0\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll   App8"

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему добавляете 2 зависимости с одинаковым содержимым. Выпилите одну из них.